# How to setup and run scala-spark in intellij?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala-spark

I am trying to run use Intellij to build spark applications written in scala. I get the following error when I execute the scala program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkConf
    at Main$.main(Main.scala:10)
    at Main.main(Main.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 2 more
```

the line throwing the error is the following one:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Sample Spark Scala Application")
```

I am not getting any error if I just try to import spark SparkConf() without trying to execute the above line.

The following are the contents of my sbt file:

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.15"

val sparkVersion = "3.2.4"

// Note the dependencies are provided
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion % "provided"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "untitled4"
  )
```

The versions mentioned in the sbt match with what I can see when I open the spark shell.

the following are the contents of my PATH, JAVA_HOME and SPARK_HOME variables

```
ray@Rayquaza-ASUS-TUF-Gaming-F15-FX506HEB-FX566HEB:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/spark/spark-3.2.4-bin-hadoop2.7/bin
ray@Rayquaza-ASUS-TUF-Gaming-F15-FX506HEB-FX566HEB:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
ray@Rayquaza-ASUS-TUF-Gaming-F15-FX506HEB-FX566HEB:~$ echo $SPARK_HOME
/usr/spark/spark-3.2.4-bin-hadoop2.7
```

I am able to run code properly in the spark shell. So spark and scala seem to be properly setup. But Intellij isn't able to use those.

I tried following a few online guides but they weren't helpful. Would appreciate help solving the problem. Also let me know if any more information or details are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run the code from inside Intellij, the spark dependencies are not "provided". Running through Intellij with default configuration, your application is going to run as a simple JVM application and should be provided all its dependencies in the classpath. Something like the below
is happening by default when you press the `Run` button in a JVM project:

```
java -classpath /path/to/dependency:/path/to/dependency_2 YourMain
```

So, my guess is that when your run the code from Intellij because your spark dependencies are marked as `provided` are nowhere to be found by `java` in the provided `classpath`.
You should change the scope of the spark packages to `compile` in your sbt file, build the project and try again.

Comment: Tried out your solution. Sadly it didn't work

Comment: Do you get the same error?

Comment: I invalidated the cache and restarted the application. The error was fixed after that

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sbt and folder structure of a sample spark scala code I ran in IntelliJ with the build.sbt contents and logs of execution

[image]

[image]

[image]